# Checkbox toggle content section not working for all checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox, accordion

I have created 4 checkbox toggle with details but same time only one checkbox toggle is working when I am clicking on another 3 toggle is not working, what do I change the script of html code so make all checkboxes work. P

```js
<!-- Check box dropdown -->
<script>
function myFunction() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  // Get the output text
  var text = document.getElementById("text");

  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
<!-- Check box dropdown -->
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
                     <label><input type="checkbox" id="chkNIRF" onclick="myFunction()"><p class="text-grey">Demo</p></label>
                     <label><input type="checkbox" id="chkNAAC" onclick="myFunction()"><p class="text-grey">Demo</p></label>
                     <label><input type="checkbox" id="chkINI" onclick="myFunction()"><p class="text-grey">Demo</p></label>
                     <label><input type="checkbox" id="chkIoE" onclick="myFunction()"><p class="text-grey">Demo</p></label>
                </div>
                
                   <p id="text" id="text" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</p>
                   <p id="text" id="text" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</p>                
                   <p id="text" id="text" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</p>                
                   <p id="text" id="text" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</p>
```

laced html and javascript code, please help to fix the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not giving the id of the checkbox to the function.

If you parse the id, your code should work:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkNIRF" onclick="myFunction('chkNIRF')">

function myFunction(x) {
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox = document.getElementById(x);
```

Based on your comments, here is a fiddle doing what you request in the comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zLvm46jw/1/

Adding indivdual ids for the p-tags

Comment: Not working...after this code only when I click any checkbox only 4th is clicked but accordion not working

Comment: I guess you are doing something wrong then. Works on this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zLvm46jw/

Comment: Thanks for reply much appreciated!  but I want accordion when I click on checkbox then below content should show. In the fiddle all text appear without clicking checkbox.

Comment: Well - You dont specify that in your original question. You need unique IDs for your P-tag, and parse the according tag into the function, if you want another position/text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234553/discussion-between-sandys-and-newguy).

Answer (score 0):

You could use event argument on the function, you can then after that get the target of the clicked checkbox like so :

```
function myFunction(event) { // Set event argument
  var checkBox = event.target; // Get the clicked checkbox
```

And on the html side you need to specify event in the function :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkNIRF" onclick="myFunction(event)">
```

Comment: after use this code only 4th checkbox accordion is working

Comment: Well is it working fine by me O.o @SandyS